# What is the maximum length of String type in AWS CloudFormation Parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can't find in the docs. I see I can set `MaxLength`, but what is the limit of `String` type?

Comment: I have not heard of a limit except in regard to MaxLength.  What other type of limit would you be referring to?

Comment: I mean can I provide a very long string parameter value?

Comment: Got it. Yes 4096

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The current "Maximum size of a parameter value" is "4,096 bytes"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html)